# What would be the impact of recently open-sourced Apple's CryptoKit lib as swift-crypto?

Tags: encryption, openssl, ios

Some of the APIs like [P-256](https://apple.github.io/swift-crypto/docs/current/Crypto/Enums/P256.html) in the [swift-crypto](https://github.com/apple/swift-crypto) are available iOS 13 onwards. If I import swift-crypto open-source lib from github into projects supporting older iOS versions, would it work? Is it possible?